# Das Genus von »Teil«: der oder das?

Tags: gender

Im Gegensatz zum Genus von *Knoblauch* oder zu dem der Nomen wie [*Joghurt, Nutella, E-Mail usw.*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/), dessen Wahl auf der Region basiert, scheint die Wahl des Genus des Nomens *Teil* wichtig zu sein[1]. In [diesem Artikel des Spielgels](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-teil-der-teil-das-a-433020.html) fand ich Hinweise auf ihre richtige Verwendung. Und zwar:

> - **Der Teil (Teil eines Ganzen):**
>     der Erdteil, der Landesteil, der Stadtteil, der Elternteil, der Bestandteil, der (vordere/hintere) Zugteil, der Mittelteil (z. B. mittlerer Abschnitt eines Buches)
> - **Das Teil (loses Stück):**
>     das Puzzleteil, das Ersatzteil, das Einzelteil, das Altenteil, das Oberteil, das Plastikteil, das Wrackteil«

Aber das Bild mit im selbigen Artikel mit dem Text

> Der hintere Teil ist das Hinterteil – logisch?

verwirrt mich wieder. Könnte jemand mit (alltäglichen) Beispielen den Unterschied erklären?

---

[1] So wichtig wie die Wahl des Artikels für *Moment* ist es vielleicht nicht (*der Moment* bedeutet Augenblick; *das Moment* ist der physikalische oder der wahrscheinlichkeitstheoretischer Begriff), aber wichtig.

Comment: Ich möchte hier gerne noch *der Schild* und *das Schild* ergänzen.

Comment: Auf welcher Region soll Jogurt, Nutella und E-Mail basieren? Des Sprechers (Hessen, Berlin, ...) oder der Sache (Bulgarien, Italien, USA)?

Comment: Schild ist doch was ganz anderes. Der Schild wird im Schwertkampf benutzt. Das Schild im modernen Leben @ThorstenDittmar

Comment: Der Schild wird immer dann verwendet, wenn es sich um einen Schutz handelt - früher wie heute. Das Schild gab es ebenfalls früher wie heute. Von daher ist das überhaupt nichts anderes - dasselbe Nomen mit unterschiedlichen Genus, die zu unterschiedlicher Bedeutung führen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Die Erklärung findet sich im selben Artikel ganz unten:

> Nach obiger Definition müssten auch die Wörter Körperteil, Vorderteil und Hinterteil männlich sein, da sie Teile eines Ganzen sind. Sie werden aber sehr häufig mit sächlichem Artikel gebraucht, das Wort „Hinterteil“ sogar fast ausschließlich. Obwohl es doch der Hintern heißt. **Offenbar wird das Hinterteil nicht als Teil eines Ganzen verstanden, sondern losgelöst vom Rest des Körpers begutachtet.** Möge sich jeder seinen Teil (nicht: sein Teil) dazu denken.

Es ist mit Hinterteil also nicht der *hintere Teil* des Körpers gemeint, sondern ein eigenständiger Körperteil wie *das Bein* oder *das Ohr*.

Die Bildunterschrift hingegen ist ironisch gemeint, da es ja eben nicht logisch ist.

Comment: Das `Hinterteil` ist `das Teil hinten`.

Comment: Auch wenn es nicht lose ist.